# Bind button visibility to the expression (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, templates

I have a delete button in each row of `GridView` (component ASP.NET). I want some of the delete buttons to be invisible. The visibility of the delete button should depend on the data that are back the row.

`GridView` is backed by `EntityDataSource`. `GridView` displays entities called `Category`, one instance in each row. Entity `Category` has (besides others) also a field of type `EntityCollection`. Name of that field is `Items`. Basically I want to allow user to delete a row only if the `Items` field of backing `Category` entity is an empty collection.

I cannot make up the binding of `Visible` property. I have no experience with bindings and Google does not really help.
This is how the button looks right now:

```
<asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                    Text="Delete" 
                    Visible=??? ></asp:Button>
```

I don't know what should replace `???`. The button schold be visible only when this expression evaluates to true:

```
((SimpleEShop.Model.Category) dataItem).Items.LongCount() <= 0
```

where `dataItem` variable contains data of current row in the table.
What is the binding that I need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

egrunin missed some things try it like this

```
Visible='<%# !(((System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<YourItemType>)Eval("Items")).Count <= 0 )%>'
```

Comment: This looks promising - it throws error saying that there is no property "LongCount" in class entity collection but that's my fault... I'll fix it(find correct property) and try again.

Comment: I modified my answer with what I think you want just replace "YourItemType" and that should work

Comment: There were two more problems in expression but finally I have this: Visible='<%# (int)Eval("Items.Count") <= 0 ? true : false %>' .Now the problem is that this evaluates to true no matter how many elements are in "Items". How do I find where is the problem ? I cannot use debugger to breakpoint in this code...

Comment: Unfortunately similar to the previous case. The expression from some reason always evaluates to false so the delete button is always unvisible. I cannot find the reason because I don't know how to debug this.

Comment: But yes as I see it both Visible='<%# (int)Eval("Items.Count") <= 0 ? true : false %>' and your expression should do what I want but they just don't...

Comment: Try displaying Items.Count in another label to verify your items have the info that you expect

Comment: Yes that what I was thinking. Entity "Category" is fetched from the database and as I don't know how exactly the fetching works in C# the property Items may be always empty because of lazy fetching... I'll try this with the label.

Comment: Im pretty sure the issue is lazy loading, you are going to need to use the method LoadWith<> when filling your datasource check out this site 
http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/07/13/eager-loading-child-entities-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Yes it is true: property Count is always empty, otherwise alejandrobog's solution would work as would the solution: Visible='<%# (int)Eval("Items.Count") <= 0 ? true : false %>'. The not initialized property Items is for other question so I accept this alejandrobog's answer.

Comment: It works! The problem with empty Items was lazy fetching from database. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

Usually I'd put this in the DataBound handler, but how about something like this:

```
Visible="<%# Eval("Items.LongCount") <= 0 ? "false" : "true";%>"
```

The quotes-within-quotes may cause errors, which is one reason I would put it in the ItemDataBound handler.

Comment: There were some problems in expression but finally I have this: Visible='<%# (int)Eval("Items.Count") <= 0 ? true : false %>' .Now the problem is that this evaluates to true no matter how many elements are in "Items". How do I find where is the problem ? I cannot use debugger to breakpoint in this code...

Comment: I would just use

Visible='<%# Eval("Items.Count") <= 0 %>'

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped on this. I try not to post without testing first, but there just wasn't time today :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to egrunin's syntax, I would just use

```
Visible='<%# Eval("Items.Count") <= 0 %>'
```